# Discover which stream print is using in python

Tags: python, windows, logging, printing, python-unittest

Is there any way to discover which stream a print call will use?

When I run my unittests with **-bv** (in Windows), print statements do not print anymore. However,  my logging module outputs still print out to the console.

My logging setup is basically:

```
    ch = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)
    ch.set_name('stdout')
    addHandler(ch, logging.DEBUG, logger_=logger)
```

So it appears to me that sys.stdout is not the same as the print statement after it has been redirected by unittest.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to force your print statement to print to sys.stdout :

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys

print("hello", file=sys.stdout)
```

Comment: I actually don't want it to print to stdout. I like the fact that print statements are not showing up when I run with -bv. I just want my logging module to behave the same way and go to the same stream as whatever print is currently set to.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that unittest redirects `sys.stdout` to a `StringIO` *after* logging has made a handler for `sys.stdout`. Before this, `sys.stdout` equals `sys.__stdout__`.

The problem was that the logging module does not ever update its handle to `sys.stdout`. It happily continues printing to the original `sys.stdout` stream reference. The solution is to detect if `sys.stdout` still equals `sys.__stdout__`. If it doesn't, then it has been redirected and you have to refresh the StreamHandler's `sys.stdout` by removing that handler and adding it again.